# Can a musician bring his used electronic organ to Indonesia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, indonesia

[image: personal used roland BK 5 OR keyboard]
Hi,
Can I bring my used  roland organ together with me exempt from custom taxes?

Comment: Will you be taking it back out of the country again? If so, then it should be exempt from customs duty.